# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Wont Connect to Wifi-Related Apps

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 that I have had for a good amount of years now has suddenly stopped being able to connect to wifi needed apps e.g. YouTube, Instagram etc...
This is really annoying and has never happened before. It all started when it wouldn't charge; I had the battery taken out and back in. When I switched it on, it let's me go on my Internet searcher and works almost perfect, but whenever I try to go on YouTube or even the Play Store, it just says "unable to connect to the Internet". I am hoping that someone can solve my problem.
Also, whenever I click on something on my Internet searcher, it keeps asking if I want to trust it... which is weird since it has never happened before. Please reply soon. Thank you for you're time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple-ish fix. Assuming you are rooted, open a root-ready file manager, and go to /system/etc. Find a file called hosts. Go into it, and delete it all, other than the first line, which should say:
127.0.0.1          localhost
(if it does not, change it to that)
Then you should be fine (May need reboot)

If you are not rooted, go onto your PC and install ODIN. Find the root file for your device on the internet, and load it in odin. Then, turn your device off, and turn it back on with power+ vol down. It should boot into download mode. Then just click start and wait.(once it's done, it may turn on by itself. That is expected, but if it doesn't happen, turn it on yourself)

Comment: Luckily for you, I had this problem twice, and this worked every time